# See available wireless access points in the terminal?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, terminal

How can I go about seeing the different AP around me using the terminal?
OpenSuse linux

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

This assumes that wlan0 is your wireless interface. To find out if it is or not type `sudo iwconfig` which will give you a list of your network interfaces and tell you which ones have wireless extensions enabled.

Comment: hmm I'm getting iwlist not found

Comment: In that case you'll have to install the wireless-tools package, which I think requires the command sudo yast2 --install wireless-tools .  However, it's been a few years since I last used opensuse so I may have got the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a six years old question and its already answered but i went in the same problem on a debian system and use this command:

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Comment: Not all debian systems use network-manager. Other than that, this is a fine answer.

Comment: This tool lists APs in color!